# Create wordpress plugin that processes and submit form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am studying how to make a plugin for wordpress, I could make a plugin that adds shortcodes to place on my page and it generates the form.

```
function mf_container($atts, $content = null) {
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    $content = str_replace("<br />","",$content);
    $content = str_replace("<p>","",$content);
    $content = str_replace("</p>","",$content);
    return 
        "<form action='".plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )."mult-form-submit.php' method='POST'>" . $content . "</form>";
}

add_shortcode('mult_form','mf_container');
```

Now precisso make this form is saved in the bank related to the logged in User.

The way that the code above when I click submit it redirects me to a page to "multi-form-submit.php". However when I get on that page I have the following code in it:

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) die("Not permited");

global $wpdb, $current_user;

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

however she has not returned since this more in the context of worpress, anyone can do it?

Comment: If please give negative to say why. So can I improve my questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a reference that has a light and after many attempts found how to do. That was the reference: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action))

I am using a plugin structure generated by [WORDPRESS PLUGIN BOILERPLATE GENERATOR](http://wppb.me/)

In it you should put what started in public view within the function: `define_public_hooks()`. In this role I had a stretch that was checked that enabled the option to use my plugin:

```
/** Set build form by shorcodes*/
if($this->get_option('mult_form')){
   $this->loader->add_action('init', $plugin_public, 'mult_form');
}
```

this section redirects me to a function of a class that controls all my public actions:

```
public function mult_form(){
    if(isset ( $_REQUEST['action']) and $_REQUEST['action'] == 'mult_form_submited'){
        $this->mult_form_submit();
    }
    $this->mult_form_shortcode();
}
```

call it two private functions, where do some treatments that will not show the code, and if all goes well, make a `include_once('partials / my_file.php');`, ed a flame a different file of course, being first where do all the treatments to generate the shortcode and the second where I will put all my treatments submission form.